# AndEngine Line.onAreaTouched not called

Tags: java, android, andengine

I have a class that extends Line and i want to detect if it is pressed.

In my class i have this:

```
public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,float pTouchAreaLocalX,
 float pTouchAreaLocalY) {


            Log.e("LINE: ", "touch");


        return true;
    }
```

I register the area in the scene, which should work because i have other areas from Sprites working.

I suppose it is because it only considers like area the central line, not the drawn area.

any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get an opportunity to test the code out, but I was looking through the AndEngine documentation for the `Line` class and managed to find this.

> onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY)
>
> *This method only fires if this Scene.ITouchArea is registered to the Scene via **registerTouchArea(ITouchArea)**.*

Use the method that is bold to register it.

Comment: Thanks for your answwer. super returns false, and i read it means "touch not managed". My problem is that onAreaTouched is not even called.

Comment: Do you think you could pastebin the class you put the onAreaTouched() function in. Other than that I'll try to solve it.

Comment: I don´t think so. It is not of my property and I already modified it to not use Line.

Comment: The area is registered. I think it is not called because it does not look at the width of the line, just at the line itself, so it is very difficult to touch a single line.